# xcode adding two strings

Tags: string, xcode

i feel retarded for even asking this because its on the tip of my tongue metaphorically but here we go

i need to make an NSString called "HTMLData" out of two already existing strings called "summaryString" and "resizingString".

where resizingString is this (how would you make this into a string?):

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;'>
```

and the summary string is decoded xml

how do i do that?

im fairly certain its something like this but its not working

NSString *HTMLData = resizingString + summaryString;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString *HTMLData = [resizingString stringByAppendingString: summaryString];
```

Refer to the [NSString Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) for more info and methods...